# How to show zero values in Inner Join for Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have two tables that I've connected by Inner Join

```
qbdsPurchTable = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PurchTable));

qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans = qbdsPurchTable.addDataSource(tableNum(VendPackingSlipTrans));
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.fetchmode(Joinmode::InnerJoin);
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.addLink(fieldNum(PurchTable, PurchId),fieldNum(VendPackingSlipTrans, OrigPurchId));
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.relations(false);
```

In my purch table, it has a lot of data but only one has a data on the VendPackingSlipTrans.

Purch Table      Vend Packing Slip Trans
PurchId             PurchId     Price
data1                 data2        1000
data2
data3
data4

What my code is doing is that:
data2 1000

but what i want to happen is that
data1 0
data2 1000
data3 0 
data4 0

by the way, I tried outer join but this is the output
data1 0 
data2 0 
data3 0
data4 0

it doesn't get the 1000 value.

Comment: Could you post the [SQL statement of the query](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/77142/142652)? Please [edit] it into your question instead of writing a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Be carefully if you use `InnerJoin`, the query returns the record with only relation having TRUE, so, it's right to having only one record (you've only match between record).

Try to use `outerjoin`

```cs
qbdsPurchTable = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PurchTable));

qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans = qbdsPurchTable.addDataSource(tableNum(VendPackingSlipTrans));
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.joinMode(Joinmode::OuterJoin);
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.addLink(fieldNum(PurchTable, PurchId),fieldNum(VendPackingSlipTrans, OrigPurchId));
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.relations(false);
```

Here is some additional information:

http://bmdax.blogspot.it/2011/05/joins-inner-outer-combined.html;
http://dynamicsaxhari.blogspot.it/2014/09/form-data-source-link-types-active.html
http://www.to-increase.com/ax-fetch-mode/
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/135626

New link: 
http://theaxapta.blogspot.it/2013/05/multiple-tables-in-query.html

The new code - **select all record** :

```cs
QueryRun queryRun;
PurchTable purchTable;
VendPackingSlipTrans vendPackingSlipTrans;
QueryBuildDataSource datasource; 
Query query;

query = new query();

datasource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PurchTable));
datasource = datasource.addDataSource(tableNum(VendPackingSlipTrans));
datasource.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);
datasource.relations(true);

queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
while (queryRun.next()) // insert this while loop to test the code
{
    purchTable = queryRun.get(tablenum(PurchTable));
    vendPackingSlipTrans = queryRun.get(tablenum(VendPackingSlipTrans));

    info(strfmt("%1 – %2", purchTable.PurchId, vendPackingSlipTrans.Price)); // insert yours fields
}
```

I show all value.

Comment: hi sir! thanks for the links. however, as indicated on my post, I already tried outjoin but it just shows zeroes.

Comment: Hi Michal Z, I'm apologize, I didn't very well your question. I not able to create a test case, but if you try use `fetchMode`  or similar way look like this link : http://theaxapta.blogspot.it/2013/05/multiple-tables-in-query.html ? 
I think the problem is about when construct the query. Good work!

Comment: Hi Michael Z, I think found any way (maybe)...see the new code attached, with only datasource (`QueryBuildDataSource datasource; `)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the join mode correctly, please replace this line

```
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.fetchmode(Joinmode::OuterJoin);
```

with

```
qbdsVendPackingSlipTrans.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);
```

Comment: hi sir, nothing happened. it just shows zeroes, it didn't get the 1000 value

Comment: Could you please show your code for retrieving the results of query execution?